# .o files in Linux and Mac OS X

Tags: linux, macos, unix, gcc

I'm not sure where I'm supposed to ask this, so excuse me if stack overflow isn't the best place.

My question is if there are any differences between a .o file generated on Linux using gcc and a .o file on Mac OS X. If so, what are the differences exactly and why couldn't I use one from Linux on Mac or vice-versa?

Comment: depends on the compilers used to produce them. if it's gcc on both sides, then they should be "the same"

Answer (score 4, accepted):

They are completely different. OS X uses the Mach-O object file format. Linux uses the ELF object file format. They perform the same general purpose but in completely different ways.

Comment: Even if they were the same format, they wouldn't necessarily be interchangeable because the operating system ABI's are different. SVR4 also uses ELF format, but you can't use an SVR4 object file on Linux.

Answer (score 0):

A file ending in .o is an object file. The compiler creates an object file for each source file, before linking them together, into the final executable. Mac OS is based on a BSD code base, while Linux is an independent development of a unix-like system. This means that these systems are similar, but not binary compatible. To get it working compile the code on the OS that you will be using.

Read more on binary code compatibility: 
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_code_compatibility